# How to override a default config option on Ext.form.Action.Submit?

Tags: extjs

Is there a way to configure ExtJS (through an Ext.override?) so that submitEmptyText config option for [Ext.form.Action.Submit](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.Action.Submit) is false by default instead of true?

I know it's possible to override methods on classes but i don't know about default config properties, one might think that since config options are mostly public properties that console logging Ext.form.Action.Submit.submitEmptyText would output false but it is undefined.

One way I succeeded is by creating an interceptor for the run method but that basically renders the submitEmptyText config option useless since it can't be set anymore through a config object passed to the constructor.

```
Ext.form.Action.Submit.prototype.run = Ext.form.Action.Submit.prototype.run.createInterceptor(function() {
    this.options.submitEmptyText = false;
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Edited a few times, but this works for me]

submitEmptyText is not actually a property of the Ext.form.Action.Submit prototype -- it is just checked in the run function as a property of the "this.options" object -- which itself is defined on the superclass, Ext.form.Action

If you want it to be globally false by default, then just set it on the options property of Ext.form.Action after it is constructed

```
Ext.form.Action.prototype.constructor = Ext.form.Action.prototype.constructor.createSequence(function() {
    Ext.applyIf(this.options, {
        submitEmptyText:false
    });
});
```

It's tricky, because the Ext.form.Action sets this.options to an empty object in its constructor, so you have to get access to that options property after the constructor executes, which is why a createSequence works in this case.

Comment: This works as expected! Indeed the submitEmptyText property isn't implemented like a component config option which is why Ext.override doesn't work, this on the other hand works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to override the Ext.form.Action.submit() for *all* instances then why not just use an Ext.override?

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Action.submit, { 
    submitEmptyText: false
});
```

Comment: Ext.override doesn't work on Ext.form.Action(s) in this case, the submitEmptyText property is implemented differently in Ext.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the **submitEmptyText** from **Ext.form.Action.submit** to be false, just set it in the config when you create the **Ext.form.Action.submit** object.

```
var submit = Ext.form.Action.submit({
    submitEmptyText: false
});
```

Comment: Ext.override doesn't work on Ext.form.Action(s) in this case, the submitEmptyText property is implemented differently in Ext.

Answer (score 0):

It is very bold to use override, however if you are able to manage that changes the right way is:

```
Ext.override ( Ext.form.Action.submit, {
   submitEmptyText: false
});
```

it will let to reverse this settings to true if needed. I also suggest to read http://edspencer.net/2009/07/extoverride-monkey-patching-ext-js.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
Ext.form.Action.submit.prototype.submitEmptyText = false.
```

This helps me with:

```
Ext.Window.prototype.constrainHeader = true;
```